# How to trace cause of failing elasticsearch bulk import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to import over 600,000 documents to my elasticsearch server.

I can import 10,000 products using the javascript client with no issues, but with all of them, I run into this issue.

```
ELASTIC_HOST="hostname:9200" node import.js --trace_debug_json=true
buffer.js:382
    throw new Error('toString failed');
    ^

Error: toString failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:382:11)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:461:33)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:441:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

The import.js is composed like this. Truncated, because it's a total of 1281687 lines.

```
if (!process.env.ELASTIC_HOST) throw new Error('set ELASTIC_HOST (example: "127.0.0.1:9200")');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({host: process.env.ELASTIC_HOST ,log:'trace'});
client.bulk({body: [
  { index: { _index: 'products', _type: 'product', _id: 12800223350 } },
  { slug: '12800223350', mfrCatNum: "945R4", name: "Heavy Duty Battery", fulltechDesc: "1 Cell; 6 V; Connection Type Screw Terminal; Used For Lantern; Heavy Duty", invoiceDescription: "6V HD Lantern Battery" , twokDesc: "1 Cell; 6 V; Connection Type Screw Terminal; Used For Lantern; Heavy Duty" },

  /* more documents here */

  { index: { _index: 'products', _type: 'product', _id: 754473940287 } },
  { slug: '754473940287', mfrCatNum: "B30-R10000-KB-16", name: "Heavy-Duty Print Ribbon", fulltechDesc: "Print Ribn", mfrDescription: "B30 Series Heavy-Duty Print Ribbon - Black/Blue", invoiceDescription: "Print Ribn" },
]}, function(err, resp) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

How can I trace the source of the error, so I can upload all my documents so I can actually evaluate elasticsearch for my current needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting an error telling you that you're trying to store too much data into a buffer (indirectly via your huge bulk call, of course, because the JS client will concatenate the bulk array into a huge string buffer). If memory serves, the maximum buffer size is 256MB, so if you have 600K documents you're probably over that limit.

I would suggest to split your call into several calls... glancing at your data, you might be able to do this in two calls, maybe three. Give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and is already very helpful. I will split up the documents and report back.

Comment: You can even remove the word probably from your answer. :)

Comment: I went down to 10k documents per bulk call, but I'm still getting the same error. I ran the node script with removing all but three bulk calls and it went through and created all 30k documents. I'm reducing the size once more and if unsuccessful then I'll go ahead and split up the JSON into multiple files.

Comment: Nice, sounds like some progress, indeed.

Comment: Splitting up the import into multiple files helped. I've learnt something here about buffers. Thx!